# WCF service in client returns 404 over https

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, web-services, wcf

`web.config` settings on the server:

```
<service name="ExporterWebService">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
              contract="IExporterWebService"/>

    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpsBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />

<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

and client `app.config` is:

```
<client>
    <endpoint 
        address="https://sample.coom/webservice/rwar.svc" 
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding" 
        contract="IRIBExporterWebService.IExporterWebService" 
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IExporterWebService"/>
</client>

<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IExporterWebService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
     <security  mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

I am trying to test out WCF with SSL and seem to be missing something, I have done a ton of searching and can't seem to find what I'm missing with the config, I have a basic WCF service hosted in IIS, I also have a test client web application that is calling the WCF service.

Please help!!! :-)

Comment: do you add https binding to server?

Comment: yes, server is ok, other client use now, just me error in client

Comment: do you have the `<security mode="Transport">` in the `<wsHttpBinding>` binding [like here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36705/7-simple-steps-to-enable-HTTPS-on-WCF-WsHttp-bindi) ?

Comment: Can you show us how that `bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"` is configured on the server?

Comment: @marc_s dear,  secureHttpBinding config in server is:  `<binding name="secureHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>`

Comment: Mr @oleksa dear, configure is similar link you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a mistake, we have tow webservice by tow address on server, &  I forgot set config https webService new on server
thank you all friends

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to type a wrong service address on the client-side when adding service reference.
[image]
The client would not generate a service endpoint created by `Wshttpbinding` when consuming a service created by `Basichttpbiding`.

> ```
> <endpoint address=""
>           binding="basicHttpBinding"
>           bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
>           contract="IExporterWebService"/>
> ```

---

> ```
>   <endpoint 
>     address="https://sample.coom/webservice/rwar.svc" 
>     binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding" 
>     contract="IRIBExporterWebService.IExporterWebService" 
>     name="BasicHttpBinding_IExporterWebService"/>
> ```

Besides, the server uses an empty relative endpoint address, while your client-side has a `webservice` prefix.

> ```
> <client>
> <endpoint 
>     address="https://sample.coom/webservice/rwar.svc" 
>     binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding" 
>     contract="IRIBExporterWebService.IExporterWebService" 
>     name="BasicHttpBinding_IExporterWebService"/>
> ```

Moreover, please trust the server certificate to establish a secure connection before making a call.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by this? What exactly is the OP doing wrong and how should they fix that?

Comment: Ok, buddy. I have completed it. please help review.